# Varnish throws 503 errors

Tags: php, nginx, magento2, varnish

I have managed to set up Redis, nginx and varnish for magento 2 in Ubuntu without SSL.

Performed all the necessary steps required to configured varnish with nginx.

There following are the configuration files.

1. /etc/default/varnish

[image: varnish]

2. /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service

[image: varnish.service]

3. /etc/varnish/default.vcl

[image: default.vcl]

4. /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento

[image: sites-available/magento]

Error log: varnishlog -q 'RespStatus == 503' -g request

```
-   Begin          req 32779 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1582114572.814013 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1582114572.814013 0.000000 0.000000
-   ReqStart       122.170.13.29 49606
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ReqHeader      Host: 13.126.114.136
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Connection: keep-alive
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: PHPSESSID=8hie1n4ddjurjoup67keoblubv; form_key=pKBGXC2YzDcWL6pi; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-cache-sessid=true; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previous=%
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 122.170.13.29
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 32781 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1582114572.814245 0.000232 0.000232
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 12:16:12 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 32780
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 32780
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1582114572.814265 0.000252 0.000019
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 282
-   RespHeader     Connection: keep-alive
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1582114572.814298 0.000285 0.000033
-   ReqAcct        1095 0 1095 269 282 551
-   End            
**  << BeReq    >> 32781     
--  Begin          bereq 32780 fetch
--  Timestamp      Start: 1582114572.814101 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    Host: 13.126.114.136
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
--  BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
--  BereqHeader    Cookie: PHPSESSID=8hie1n4ddjurjoup67keoblubv; form_key=pKBGXC2YzDcWL6pi; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-cache-sessid=true; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previous=%
--  BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 122.170.13.29
--  BereqHeader    grace: none
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 32781
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  FetchError     no backend connection
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1582114572.814144 0.000042 0.000042
--  Timestamp      Error: 1582114572.814148 0.000046 0.000004
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   503
--  BerespReason   Service Unavailable
--  BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
--  BerespHeader   Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 12:16:12 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
--  BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Storage        malloc Transient
--  ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
--  ObjStatus      503
--  ObjReason      Backend fetch failed
--  ObjHeader      Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2020 12:16:12 GMT
--  ObjHeader      Server: Varnish
--  ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
--  ObjHeader      Retry-After: 5
--  Length         282
--  BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
--  End
```

Tried several solutions found here but none seems to be working.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text, use text instead.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I will update.

Comment: Why negative votes? It didn't work. I exhausted all the solutions then posted it.

Comment: Negative votes, see my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

The `varnishlog` tells you `no backend connection`, which would likely mean a failed health check.

To confirm, run `varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_Health`

A side note: It is best to set the `pub` directory of Magento to be the webroot (`root` directive in NGINX) for security reasons. Subsequently, edit the VCL file to *remove* `pub` from the health check, because all the web-accessible paths will be relative to the webroot.

It may be also misconfiguration of the stack. In your configs, NGINX listens on the loopback interface `127.0.0.1`. But in Varnish you set the backend to `localhost`. In some situations, this may resolve to IPv6's loopback interface `::1` and Varnish may be failing connection to NGINX because it does not listen on `::1`. So it helps to be consistent and put `127.0.0.1` in the VCL file to ensure it is talking to the right interface where NGINX listens on.

Once that this is corrected, confirm the NGINX listen interface is accessible, by e.g. trying to `telnet` in:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
```

If you don't get connection refused messages, NGINX's `listen` interface is accessible. Otherwise, there are further corrections to be made.